# Javascript string vs Variable value difference

Tags: javascript

I wanted to compare the value of variable which is getting the URL of current page with the hard coded string. Though the values are same I am getting false in the comparison. Not able to guess what is happening. Below is the code:

```
var loc = String('"' + window.URL + '"');

if("Here I am specifying entire URL manually exactly same which I am getting in loc"==String(loc)) 
{ console.log("true") } 
else { console.log("false") }
```

This is pretty simple but I am missing something. Help needed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"Though the values are same I am getting false in the comparison."* Then, by definition, the values are **not** the same. There's some small difference you've missed. Perhaps capitalization, or whitespace at the beginning or end, or even hidden characters somewhere. Using your debugger, examine both strings in really, really fine detail; you'll find a difference somewhere. It may help to output each string as a series of code unit values: `console.log(theString.split("").map(ch => ch.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).padStart(2, "0")));` We can't do that for you without the strings. *(not my dv)*

Comment: If you see loc return ""function URL() { [native code] }"" , and hence you are seeing false .

Comment: @T.J.Crowder as you said there was a difference in both the strings I didn't much understood the output of match function But yes debugging helped. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use window.location.href instead . Since loc variable returns `"function URL() { [native code] }"` Hence the result is false.

```js
window.location.href === "<Your string>"
```

Comment: This is perfect. Solved my problem. Can you please elaborate for "function URL() { [native code] }" a bit for understanding purpose.

Comment: Just do console.log(String(window.URL)) , you will get to know that URL is a function. , it will not return as you are expecting